# Terminate metacity

Tags: metacity

The last two lines of my `.xinitrc` looks like this

```
xterm -g 80x24+10+10 -bg black -fg green &
metacity
```

When I used `twm`, I could exit it from the menu (return to the `tty` where I run `xinit`), but how do you exit `metacity`? The `man metacity` does not mention this, but it refers to the panel menu (which I don't have). Maybe it's there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

metacity is not intended to be exited, since it is generally only meant to be used with a session manager. You will need to use an external tool to kill it.

Comment: Yes, I see a `metacity` process on `ps -A`. Instinctively, I don't like to `pkill` things but do you see any harm doing it in this case? (I mean, regularly.) More generally, what decides when you return to the `tty` after running `xinit`? Is it when there are no processes left running or is there a specific command that is invoked?

Comment: Killing metacity is usually safe regardless of the presence of a session manager. The X server deinitializes when all its children die.